# Structure return type interpretation

Tags: c

When I refer `int func(int a,int b)`, it means we are referring to function that will return integer data. What does the following statement mean:

```
struct datatype func(int a, int b);
```

I know the function is going to return a structure type, but how exactly can I interpret it. I mean in case of integer return type, it was returning a whole number, let's say 5; in the second case what kind of data should I expect, since a structure contains mixture of data types sometimes?

For example:

```
struct datatype
{
    int a;
    float b;
    char array[8];
    int *ptr;
};
```

What type will it return then, because struct contains a mix of many data types?

Comment: **Before** `struct datatype func(int a,int b)` is declared, `struct datatype` will have been defined.  `func()` returns data as defined by that `struct`.  To fully answer the question, look to that prior  `struct datatype` definition.

Comment: struct datatype{int a ;float b; char array[8],int *ptr}. What type will it return then , because struct contains mix of all datatypes?

Comment: Find a good beginner's book. It will tell you how not much is true and even less is permitted.

Comment: The type `func()` returns just that: a structure call `data` containing an `int`, `float`, array 8 of `char` and a pointer.  `struct data` **is** the type.

Comment: struct types are just cartesian products

Answer (score 3):

When a function is declared to return an `int`, it returns an `int`.

When a function is declared to return a `double *`, it returns a `double *`.

When a function is declared to return a `struct datatype`, it returns a `struct datatype`.

Given:

```
struct datatype
{
    int a;
    float b;
    char array[8];
    int *ptr;
};

struct datatype func(int a, int b);
```

You could write code like this inside another function:

```
struct datatype rv = func(1, 2);
```

and now you can use any and all of the elements of `rv` because the return value was copied into the variable, just the same as you could write:

```
double dv = sqrt(3.1415926538);
```

In all these examples, the function returns a value of the type it is declared to return.  You can save the return value; you can (but probably shouldn't) ignore it.  Within limited contexts, you can use the returned value immediately as an argument to a function, or to assign part of the return value to a variable of an appropriate type.  Note that you can't apply the `&` (address of) operator to the result of a function call; it is not an lvalue.

This code illustrates the options available to you:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

struct DataType
{
    double  d;
    int     i;
    char    s[20];
};

static struct DataType function(double a1, int a2, char *a3)
{
    struct DataType rv;
    rv.d = a1;
    rv.i = a2;
    strncpy(rv.s, a3, sizeof(rv.s));
    rv.s[sizeof(rv.s)-1] = '\0';
    return rv;
}

static void printer(struct DataType dt)
{
    printf("d = %f; i = %d; s = [%s]\n", dt.d, dt.i, dt.s);
}

int main(void)
{
    function(0, 0x0, "");
    printer(function(3.14159265358979323844, 0x03C0, "Slice of the pie"));
    printf("d = %f\n", function(2.71828182845904523536, 0x2203, "Existential").d);
    struct DataType dt = function(1.61803398874989484820, 0x03A6, "Oh fie upon a phi");
    printf("d = %f; i = %d; s = [%s]\n", dt.d, dt.i, dt.s);
    double d = function(1.41421356237309504880, 0x221A, "I'm rooting for two").d;
    printf("d = %f\n", d);
    return 0;
}
```

The output from that is:

```
d = 3.141593; i = 960; s = [Slice of the pie]
d = 2.718282
d = 1.618034; i = 934; s = [Oh fie upon a phi]
d = 1.414214
```

Answer (score 2):

A `struct` is a product type. It contains one value for *each* of its elements, and *each* element can have a different type. In memory, it's a bunch of data, one piece per element, lain out in a row (roughly). A `union` is the opposite. It contains exactly *one* value of *one* type, but you don't know exactly which type that is, because there are multiple choices. In memory, it's one area containing one value of ambiguous type.

In your example, `func` returns an `int` *and* a `float` *and* a `char[8]` *and* an `int*`.

```
struct datatype data = func(...);
int int1 = data.a;
float fl = data.b;
char* ch = data.array;
int *int2 = data.ptr;
// Four values and four types in one package
```

In this example, we have a union:

```
union datatype
{
    int a;
    float b;
    char array[8];
    int *ptr;
};
union datatype func();
```

Now, `func` returns an `int` *or* a `float` *or* a `char[8]` *or* an `int*`, and you decide which one you think it is when you access it.

```
union datatype data = func();
if(testSomething1())
{
    int int1 = data.a; // I think that func gave me an int, so I'll take it out
}
else if(testSomething2())
{
    float fl = data.b; // I think func gave me a float in this branch
}
else if(testSomething3())
{
    char* ch = data.array; // If testSomething3(), then func() returns a char[8]
}
else
{
    int *int2 = data.ptr; // Otherwise, it's an int*
}
// One value with 4 choices of type.
// You can also do evil things like
// union { float f; int i } u;
// u.i = 500;
// something(u.f);
// Which reinterprets an int as a float. Sometimes that makes sense, but most times
// you've done something wrong.
```

A `union` is what you'd call something of "mixed type", because the type of an `union`'s value really is ambiguous. A `struct`, however, is not mixed. It contains multiple, separate pieces of data, and each piece has its own, clear type.